# How to insert a flat file into oracle db using awk command in Unix shell script

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I am new to Shell script and I want to insert a flat file into oracle DB(Unix OS).

Flat File Eg(Separated By Comma)

```
Name,Male,B.Tech,Chennai
Name1,Male,BE,Kolkatta
Name2,Female,BE,Delhi
```

The number of fields in flat file may vary(need not be 4 only).

I have tried the below commands

```
awk '{print "INSERT INTO EMP VALUES(" $1 c, q $2 q, c $3, ");";}' q="'" c="," FS=, Details.bat
```

It is printing the SQL Query and also the number of fields are fixed in the above commands.

Kindly help me to solve the issue.

Thanks & Regards
Prakash

Comment: Is only the second field supposed to be quoted? Because it looks like that from your attempt. If not, please explain which fields ought to be quoted.

Comment: On another note, it might be better to use [SQL*Loader](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL*Loader_FAQ) to load CSV files into an Oracle database. It's made for the task, after all.

Answer (score 1):

no very clear what do you want to get, this awk one-liner generates following output:

```
awk -F',' -v q="'" '{printf "INSERT INTO EMP VALUES(%s,%s%s%s,%s);\n",$1,q,$2,q,$3;}' file
```

output

```
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES(Name,'Male',B.Tech);
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES(Name1,'Male',BE);
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES(Name2,'Female',BE);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear how you decide which fields to quote and which not to, or how you decide which fields to print but here's a solution that quotes all of the output fields and assumes you just don't want to output the last field on each line:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN{ FS="," }
{
    printf "INSERT INTO EMP VALUES( "
    for (i=1;i<NF;i++) {
        printf "%s'%s'", (i>1?", ":""), $i
    }
    print " );"
}
$ 
$ awk -f tst.awk file
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES( 'Name', 'Male', 'B.Tech' );
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES( 'Name1', 'Male', 'BE' );
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES( 'Name2', 'Female', 'BE' );
```

If that's not what you want and you can't figure out how to adapt it to what you want, edit your question to provide a better explanation and the expected output to go with your sample input.